# How to use EXEC combine with SET clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to use dinamic query with exec clause to set some variable in sql server, but not work properly.

My code is like this :

```
DECLARE
    @ProjectCode    varchar(25),
    @TypeCode       varchar(25),
    @BomDate        varchar(25),
    @TbNameBom      varchar(25),
    @BomProgressCal int

SET @ProjectCode    = 'PRO160604'
SET @TypeCode       = 'PS-BPRG15AGW'
SET @BomDate        = '8/19/2016'
SET @TbNameBom      = 'z'+@TypeCode

EXEC('
SET  @BomProgressCal        = (SELECT AVG([Bod Progress]) FROM  [PMLite].[dbo]. ['+@TbNameBom+']
                               WHERE ([Project Code]    = @ProjectCode) AND
                                     ([Type Code]       = @TypeCode)    AND
                                     ([Bom Date]        = @BomDate))
')  

PRINT @BomProgressCal
```

This error appears:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ProjectCode".

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set @BomProgressCal within context of EXEC function, so you can't update it directly as it's not visible.

You can implement INSERT INTO "temp table" EXEC (sql_code) method to retrieve any data from dynamic sql query. Then just query that temp table.

To pass parameters to dynamic query, you can use sp_execute_sql or just use REPLACE function to replace tokens (like '@TypeCode' with actual value) - don't forget here to replace ' with '' for any varchar/char/nvarchar values.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass variables willy nilly between dynamic sql (which you do not at all need in this example anyway) and the outer code ... when the dynamic sql is executed it has no idea what @BomProgressCal is because that is a different context.

If you have to use dynamic sql, rather than the EXEC command, I would suggest using [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which allows you to pass variable values through regular and output parameters.

In general, I would suggest not using dynamic sql unless that is really your only option because almost always (like this example) its use is unwarranted.